# Creating reverse average calculation with constraints in python

Tags: python, sympy, solver

I am trying to work out how to use `solver()` from SymPy in python to solve my algebra problem with constraints.

I have two mystery values XX and YY that need to average to ZZ, where XX and YY both need to be greater than "lower_constraint" and less than "upper_constraint".

I know that if I needed to find XX or YY, if I already knew one of these values and ZZ, I could simply use solver from sympy.

For an example where I know XX = 35 and ZZ = 42, I can easily find the correct YY for XX and YY to average to ZZ using basic algebra as so:

```
((35 + x) / 2) = 42
2 * ((35 + x) / 2) = 42 * 2
35 + x = 84
x = 84 - 35
x = 49
```

and so here XX = 49

and now written for SymPy we set the right side of the equation to 0:

expr = ((35 + X) / 2) - 42

and so writing the whole code as:

```
x = symbols('x')
expr = ((35 + X) / 2) - 42
sol = solve(expr)
```

And this solves it. Great.

But now I want to do something a little more complicated. Here we had a straightforward solution, because there is only one value to go with 35 to get an exact average of 42.

What if we have our ZZ value of 42, but we do not know either of the two values XX and YY that make up this average? There would be an infinite list of value pairs that could average to 42.

In my problem, I have two constraints, that I will declare as constraint1 = 2 and constraint 2 = 104

And so, then I would solve for all the pairs of values that are both > 2 and less than 104 that average to 42. There may still be many.

However, what I am trying to figure out here is from this list of pairs is the widest apart pair, such that I would pull both the lowest and highest possible values as a pair to average to 42 meeting my constraints.

How can I augment my code to calculate/print these two values using `solver()` from `SymPy`?

Comment: I don't think sympy is the right tool for this job. I would try it with numpy/scipy and set up an optimization problem. Or maybe use ad hoc optimization libraries like Pyomo or Gekko...

Comment: Using either of the constraint equations gives another equation so you have two equations for two unknowns. SymPy's solve function can solve that for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider integer values, this is a diophantine problem:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> diophantine(x+y-42*2)
{(t_0, 84 - t_0)}
```

You want each of those values to be between 2 and 104 so

```py
>>> X, Y = _.pop()
>>> solve([X>2,X<104,Y>2,Y<104])
(2 < t_0) & (t_0 < 82)
```

So your `x = t_0` must be greater than 2 and less than 82 and `y` will have the corresponding value needed to make the average 42, i.e. `84 - t_0`. The difference `y - x` will by `84 - 2*t_0`; if you want that to be as large as possible, pick the smallest `t_0`.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. This definitely appears to be what I was looking for, but I am just trying to understand what each of your variables represents here. I have been referring to the SymPy documentation on `diophantine()`. What does `t_0` represent here in the given tuple? Solutions to the given equation? And in the second code chunk, you set these constraints and then run `diophantine()?` When I run the code I get this error: `AttributeError: 'And' object has no attribute 'pop'`. I am just trying tsso understand the steps here so I can understand this all conceptually! Thanks!

Comment: When there are infinite solutions, diophantine uses a parameter to indicate an arbitrary integer. The order of expressions/symbols in the tuple matches the symbols of the expression in sorted order. Note that in the second step I am running `solve` not `diophantine`. The code was intended to be run each step after the other; try cut and paste of what I showed.